# JQuery: How 'select' radio button by clicking on submit button?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm newbie in JQuery and I need to 'select' radio button by clicking on submit button in this table, just before JQuery postback function.

[image]

I apologize that my codes specially JQuery are too much messy and amateur.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('.button-cart').on('click', function() {
    btn_id = $(this).attr('id');
    qty_id = '#input-quantity' + btn_id.replace('button-cart', '');
    input_qty_val = $(qty_id);
    $('#input-quantity').val(input_qty_val.val());

    radio_id = $(this).closest('input[type=radio]').attr('id');
    alert(radio_id);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#product input[type=\'text\'], #product input[type=\'hidden\'], #product input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #product input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #product select, #product textarea'),
        dataType: 'json'
    });
});
//--></script>
```

Submit Button and Radio Input are in different cells of table.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" id="option-229-26" name="option[229]" value="26">
                        70B </label>
                </div></td>
            <td> 12 </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="2" id="input-quantity-229-26" class="qty form-control"></td>
            <td><button type="button" id="button-cart-229-26" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="button-cart btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" id="option-229-27" name="option[229]" value="27">
                        75B </label>
                </div></td>
            <td> 12 </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="2" id="input-quantity-229-27" class="qty form-control" autocomplete="off"></td>
            <td><button type="button" id="button-cart-229-27" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="button-cart btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" id="input-quantity" value="3">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From JQuery standpoint, the code doesn't seem to be so messy, but I suggest you change HTML structure. Matching input groups by part of ID requires the script to make replaces and concats for collecting inputs. With data-attributes the script can collect values way easier.

For example you can mark inputs that belong to one group with `data-input-group="chart-group-<id>"` or whatever attribute you choose. So then all appropriate inputs can be selected from JQuery simply with:

```
$('input[type="radio"][data-input-group="chart-group-<id>"]');
```

... and so on.

```js
$('.button-cart').on('click', function() {
  group_id = $(this).data('input-group');
  $('#input-quantity').val(
    $('input[name=quantity][data-input-group=' + group_id + ']').val()
  );

  $('input[type=radio][data-input-group=' + group_id + ']').prop("checked", true);

  // and perform ajax request
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
                        <input type="radio" data-input-group="chart-group-229" value="26">
                        70B </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td> 12 </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="2" data-input-group="chart-group-229" class="qty form-control"></td>
      <td><button type="button" data-input-group="chart-group-229" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="button-cart btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
      <td>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
                        <input type="radio" data-input-group="chart-group-239" value="26">
                        70B </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td> 12 </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="quantity" value="21" size="2" data-input-group="chart-group-239" class="qty form-control"></td>
      <td><button type="button" data-input-group="chart-group-239" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="button-cart btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" id="input-quantity" value="3">
```

Comment: Very interesting! I'll be thankful if you give me little more detail especially HTML and how to Check the radio button.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me, I really do appreciate it! (http://bindexo.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=52)

Comment: Sir, for my project, I need a freelancer's help. I'll be glad if you contact me: kardo & gmail com.

Comment: Thank you, I'd be glad to help you with that if you`re interested, but gmail returns an error, account kardo & gmail com does not exist. Please check if the address is correct. Or you can contact me: rv.oleg.ua & gmail com

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

**Explanation:**

I commented out the `ajax` since I am not using it, then I access the parent `tr` using the `.parents()` function, the I find (`.find()`) the input which has the checkbox (`input:checkbox`), then finally I set the property `checked` to true, using the `.prop()` function.

```js
$('.button-cart').on('click', function() {
  btn_id = $(this).attr('id');
  qty_id = '#input-quantity' + btn_id.replace('button-cart', '');
  input_qty_val = $(qty_id);
  $('#input-quantity').val(input_qty_val.val());

  radio_id = $(this).parents("tr").find("input:radio");
  radio_id.prop("checked", true);

  /*$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#product input[type=\'text\'], #product input[type=\'hidden\'], #product input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #product input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #product select, #product textarea'),
    dataType: 'json'
  });*/
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="option[229]" value="27">
                        75B </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td> 12 </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="2" id="input-quantity-229-27" class="qty form-control"></td>
      <td><button type="button" id="button-cart-229-27" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="button-cart btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="option[229]" value="28">
                        80B </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td> 12 </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="2" id="input-quantity-229-28" class="qty form-control"></td>
      <td><button type="button" id="button-cart-229-28" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="button-cart btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" id="input-quantity" value="3">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm sorry for inconvenience! Your code is very nice and useful, but the other one was more helpful.

Comment: @Kardo ok that's fine, just wanted to know if my code failed somewhere!